# Display numbers an odd number of times in C

Tags: c, for-loop

An output is given in the following form :

```
OUTPUT :
0
111
22222
3333333
... up to 9.
```

The task I was given was to write a code for this output using nested `for` loops.

The closest I have gotten to figuring it out is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=0, y=0, z=0;

    for (x=1; x<=9; x=x+1)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (y=0; y<=10; y=y+1)
        {
            for(z==y; y<x; y++)
            {
                printf("%d", x);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was also instructed to "Refrain from using Arrays or others methods of solving this question."

I cant figure out my mistake. Help would be appreciated.

The output from this program is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfNPe.png

Comment: Use a debugger to figure it out?

Comment: Not have the know how of a debugger yet.

Comment: `printf("0 111 22222 3333333 ... uptil 9"); for(;;) for(;;) return 1;`

Comment: If you don;t have/know how to use a debugger, then put print statements wherever you want to know what is going on.

Comment: @George `for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) printf("I will not throw paper airplanes in class\n");`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I shall try that method, thank you.

Comment: @George: Why `return 1` inside and why nesting infinite loops?

Comment: @Olaf The joke doesn't make sense now as the q's been edited :( It originally said something like "How can I print 0 111 22222 3333333 ... uptil 9 using nested for loops?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate all numbers (`x`), while incrementing the number of prints (`y`) by 2, strting from `1` ([see online](https://ideone.com/PXVfSU)):

```
for (int x = 0, y = 1; x <= 9; x++, y += 2)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < y; z++)
            printf("%d", x);        
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

I would say

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < x * 2 + 1; y++)
                printf("%d", x);
        printf("\n")
}
```

is more elegant, but it can be a little tricky to follow.

Comment: Why not just `x++`?

Comment: I do need to understand the logic though.

Comment: @SyedHasan I changed it so it would be easier to understand. Every time you increment `x` by one, and the number of prints `y` by two, starting from `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciated!

Comment: Too complicated. Why not simply step by 2?

Comment: @Olaf please explain

Comment: Just that: There is no need for two variables in the outer loop.

Comment: @UrielEli: Which is bad coding style. Don't put expressions into the loop-control which are not related for loop control. Putting all code into a single line is the opposite of good advice.

Comment: @Olaf I mean the `y <= x * 2 + 1`, not the `printf`, and fixed.

Comment: Still not clear why you print a space. Should be a linebreak.

Comment: @Olaf OP probably edited question. It was `0 111 22222` before.

Comment: Yes, but that was long before your last edits. Anyway, I removed the DV. Although It is spoon-feeding OP instead of really helping. For homework questions which show at least some code&effort (others are off-topic here), it is better to point at the errors on the original code, not just provide your own code without explanation. Feeding fish vs. teaching how to fish, you know ...

Answer (score 1):

That would be then:

```
int main()
{
    int x, y, z;

    printf("0");
    for (x=1, y=3; x<=9; x++, y+=2)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (z=y; z; z--)
        {
            printf("%d", x);    
        }       
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
111
22222
3333333
444444444
55555555555
6666666666666
777777777777777
88888888888888888
9999999999999999999
```

Comment: This logic is what I was closest to, will give it a shot. Thanks @Paul